# Inheritable chmod permission from parent directory

Tags: permissions, directory, chmod

I have a directory named `cache` in `/var/www`, where I need to provide permission in following way:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 cache
```

but that's not enough because PHP script automatically creates sub-directories under that for better file management like `a`, `b`, `c`... and so on. Now here whenever any new directory gets created it does not inherit permission from parent directory "cache" instead it stays with `drwxr-xr-x` access instead of `drwxrwxrwx`.

Can anyone help?

Comment: Google 'php' and 'umask'. Also that's not really Ubuntu related. You can also use php's `chmod()` function every time the new directory is created or create a cronjob that runs `chmod -R 777 var/www/cache`.

Comment: I understand but just coined this question here as I was using ubuntu. Next time I will be posting it on common linux question website.

Comment: try `chmod -R 2777 cache', theoretically that first 2, called "a sticky bit" I think, should make files and directories inherit permissions

Comment: hm.. tried that.. theoretically it should but I think it's not doing it as expected as of now.

Comment: That first 2 is called gid, not sticky bit. It only makes the group 'inherit' and nothing else. To inherit permissions, explore the `setfacl` command.

Answer (score 1):

This is the intended behaviour of the UNIX `umask` feature, which is used to control the permissions of newly created files.

For example, with a `umask` of `0022`, the group and world write bits will be masked out.  This likely explains the results you saw with the directories your script creates.

You might be able to adjust the `umask` in PHP to `0000`, but as this is a process global setting and the PHP interpreter is embedded in Apache, it might have security implications beyond your script.  The alternative is to issue a `chmod()` call after creating the directory, which should be a bit safer and doesn't depend on the `umask` setting.

You might also want to consider whether you really need to make these directories world writeable.  If the files need to be writeable by the web server and some other script, perhaps you could set the directory to be owned by a common group for those two environments and only make it group writeable.